# How do I replace the values in a column of data that lie within a certain range?

Tags: matlab

I have a column of data and for different rages I want to replace the values of this column with a certain value. For example, for all the values between 6 and 15 I want to replace with 10. For all values between 16 and 25 I want to replace with 20 etc. What is the easiest way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Logical indexing:

```
y=rand(1, 50)
y(y>0.5) = 1
y
```

The above replaces the elements of `y` greater than 0.5 with 1

You could use `find` as well, but logical indexing is the obvious way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. My values range from 0 to 1308, so I would need to repeat this 130 times since I want to do it for ranges of ten. Is there a more efficient way rather entering y(y>=a & y<=b)= c, 130 times for different values of a, b and c?

Comment: Looks like you want to do some binning, and replace values in a certain range with the "median" value of that range? See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

if it's all like in your example, you can use this:

```
y=randint(100,1,1309)+1; % generate data sample

y=10*floor((y+4)/10) % 'round' to 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do some binning, and replace values in a certain range with the "median" value of that range? Below is the code for the basic principle to follow. Use HISTC. The only thing you may need to change below are the "edges", but otherwise, this should do the trick:

```
x = round(rand(1,1000)*1400); % Sample data

intervalSize = 10; % 5 to 15, 15 to 25 etc.

maxEdge = max(x) + intervalSize - mod(max(x), intervalSize);
edges = 0:intervalSize:max(x);
[n bin] = histc(x,edges); % Don't really need 'n'

for i = 1: (numel(edges) - 1)
    midValue = mean([edges(i) edges(i+1)]);
    x(bin == i) = midValue;
end
```

And here's another approach that does NOT use HISTC, but relies purely on logical indexing.

```
%% Approach 2:
x = round(rand(1,1000)*1400); % Sample data
intervalSize = 10;
maxEdge = max(x) + intervalSize - mod(max(x), intervalSize);
edges = 0:intervalSize:max(x);

for i = 1: (numel(edges) - 1)
    midValue = mean([edges(i) edges(i+1)]);
    x(x >= edges(i) & x < edges(i+1)) = midValue;
end
```

You may need to adjust the logical indexing condition to get exactly what you want, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way.

```
a = rand(1308, 1)*1308; % replace with your column

target = [10 20]; % replace with your targets and ranges
left = [6 15];
right = [16 25];

for i=1:length(target)
    a(a>=left(i)&a<right(i)) = target(i);
end
```